# How to use Cmake string regex replace to get last part of path url from multiple instances of path urls and replace the whole path with it

Tags: regex, cmake, cmake-language

So my string is as follows:

```
TESTA:C:/Users/mycode/dir_a/./result_a/out_stra.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_b/./result_b/out_strb.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_c/./result_c/out_strc.bin
TESTB:C:/Users/mycode/dir_a/./result_a/out_stra.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_b/./result_b/out_strb.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_c/./result_c/out_strc.bin
TESTC:C:/Users/mycode/dir_a/./result_a/out_stra.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_b/./result_b/out_strb.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_c/./result_c/out_strc.bin
```

My required output is:

```
TESTA:out_stra.bin;out_strb.bin;out_strc.bin
TESTB:out_stra.bin;out_strb.bin;out_strc.bin
TESTC:out_stra.bin;out_strb.bin;out_strc.bin
```

I tried with string regex but I'm not getting the required output. Here is what I tried:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "C:/Users/mycode/.*/\./.*/"
       "" TEMP
       <inputfilecontent>)
```

will be grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: Try `[A-Z]:(/([^/;]+))+` and replace with `\\2`. Not sure about the right syntax in your case, probably, `string(REGEX REPLACE "[A-Z]:(/([^/;]+))+" "\\2" TEMP ${inputfilecontent})`

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your suggestion, its only giving me the last bin and ignoring the other bin files before that

Comment: Strange, as if you did not have `;` between the values.  Maybe there are no spaces in the paths? Try `[A-Z]:(/([^/; \t\n]+))+`

Comment: @deb: On Stack Overflow a question is perfectly allowable to be modified by the author for add information about the problem. So, instead of deleting your [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69928627/read-each-line-of-a-file-and-replace-a-url-string-in-the-file-with-the-end-part) and asking a new one about the very same problem it is better to edit the old one.

Comment: Thanks alot @WiktorStribiżew The last suggestion helped me a lot with parsing multiple lines with similar path strings (I have modified the question based on that), but still I get a single bin for each line, so the ".bin"s seperated with ";" is not concatenated somehow

Comment: That makes me think `;` is not parsed as `;`. Not sure how to help you if you cannot use a delimiter in the regex.

Comment: I have come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18805127/3832970), try replacing the `;` with `$<SEMICOLON>`. Something like `string(REGEX REPLACE "[A-Z]:(/([^/$<SEMICOLON> \t\n]+))+" "\\2" TEMP ${inputfilecontent})`. Or, try escaping it, `[A-Z]:(/([^/\; \t\n]+))+`. I see there are so many suggestions, but unfortunately, I cannot test it.

Comment: Or, try escaping it, `[A-Z]:(/([^/\; \t\n]+))+`. I see there are so many suggestions, but unfortunately, I cannot test it.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew i tested both  with escape \; and $<SEMICOLON> not working. The escape is giving me the last ".bin" like before and <SEMICOLON> is not working at all

Comment: Try https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_filename_component.html with NAME mode.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all you answers guys, I was able to find the final solution, had to do something before adding @WiktorStribiżew solution. I had to do

```
string(REGEX REPLACE ";" "\\\\;" output "${input}")
```

to make the solution work with ";"

Answer (score 0):

Regex `.` matches any character, including semicolon (`;`) and newline (`\n`). This is why part `.*` of your regex matches all intermediate "records" of your file.

So you need to replace `.` in your regex with `[^;\n]`, which doesn't match delimiters of your records:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "C:/Users/mycode/[^;\n]*/\./[^;\n]*/"
       "" TEMP
       "<inputfilecontent>")
```

Note also, that you need to enclose content of your file into **double quotes**. The thing is that your file contains semicolons `;`, which in unquoted form are interpreted by CMake as **arguments delimiters**.

Specific of [string(REGEX REPLACE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-replace) is that it concatenates all input arguments, so without quotes semicolons will be lost.

---

Runnable example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(replace_lines)

set(LINES
[=[
TESTA:C:/Users/mycode/dir_a/./result_a/out_stra.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_b/./result_b/out_strb.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_c/./result_c/out_strc.bin
TESTB:C:/Users/mycode/dir_a/./result_a/out_stra.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_b/./result_b/out_strb.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_c/./result_c/out_strc.bin
TESTC:C:/Users/mycode/dir_a/./result_a/out_stra.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_b/./result_b/out_strb.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_c/./result_c/out_strc.bin
]=]
)
message(STATUS "Lines: ${LINES}")

string(REGEX REPLACE "C:/Users/mycode/[^;\n]*/\./[^;\n]*/"
    "" RESULT
    "${LINES}"
)

message(STATUS "Result: ${RESULT}")
```

Output:

```
-- Lines: TESTA:C:/Users/mycode/dir_a/./result_a/out_stra.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_b/./result_b/out_strb.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_c/./result_c/out_strc.bin
TESTB:C:/Users/mycode/dir_a/./result_a/out_stra.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_b/./result_b/out_strb.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_c/./result_c/out_strc.bin
TESTC:C:/Users/mycode/dir_a/./result_a/out_stra.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_b/./result_b/out_strb.bin;C:/Users/mycode/dir_c/./result_c/out_strc.bin

-- Result: TESTA:out_stra.bin;out_strb.bin;out_strc.bin
TESTB:out_stra.bin;out_strb.bin;out_strc.bin
TESTC:out_stra.bin;out_strb.bin;out_strc.bin
```

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately its not affecting the strings at all, i am getting the same strings in my output

Comment: I have added the exact code which works for me. Please, check whether it works for you.

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev This worked as well, many thanks